# I am unable to create user with email and password with firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create user with email and password and then store their details if the task is successful in firebase database for reference purpose but I don't know what happen. The progressDialog keeps loading without creating the user. Here is the code. Please I will appreciate if anyone can put me through on it

```
private void registerSeller() {
  String sellerName = name.getText().toString();
  String phoneNumber = phone.getText().toString();
  String sellerEmail = email.getText().toString();
  String sellerPassword = password.getText().toString();
  String sellerAddress = address.getText().toString();

  if (sellerName.isEmpty()) {
    name.setError("Please Enter Your Name");
    `enter code here`
    cancel = true;
    name.requestFocus();
  } else if (phoneNumber.isEmpty()) {
    phone.setError("Please Enter Your Phone Number");
    cancel = true;
    phone.requestFocus();
  } else if (sellerEmail.isEmpty()) {
    email.setError("Please Enter Your Email Address");
    cancel = true;
    email.requestFocus();
  } else if (sellerPassword.isEmpty()) {
    password.setError("Please Enter Your Password");
    cancel = true;
    password.requestFocus();
  } else if (sellerAddress.isEmpty()) {
    address.setError("Please Enter Your Shop Address");
    cancel = true;
    address.requestFocus();
  } else {
    loadingDialog.setTitle("Registration Processing...");
    loadingDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we are checking your credentials");
    loadingDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    loadingDialog.show();
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(sellerEmail, sellerPassword)
      .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            final DatabaseReference sellerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            String sid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            HashMap < String, Object > sellerMap = new HashMap < > ();
            sellerMap.put("sid", sid);
            sellerMap.put("name", sellerName);
            sellerMap.put("phone", phoneNumber);
            sellerMap.put("email", sellerEmail);
            sellerMap.put("password", sellerPassword);
            sellerMap.put("address", sellerAddress);
            sellerRef.child("sellers").child(sid)
              .updateChildren(sellerMap)
              .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Void > () {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Void > task) {
                  if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(SellerRegistrationActivity.this, "Seller Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SellerRegistrationActivity.this, SellerLoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                  } else {
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(SellerRegistrationActivity.this, "Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                }
              });

        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: There is no error message, it is not creating the user, the progressdialog keeps loading forever and if i remove it, the issue is still the same as the user is not created. I have enabled sign in with email and password in the firebase authentication yet I can not create any user

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: No, I think that is where the error is coming because if that other part work, the data will be saved. But I don't really know what is wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

The first step in troubleshooting is to stop ignoring potential errors. If a `Task` fails, it has an exception that explains what caused it to fail. You should log or raise that exception, to find the root cause:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(sellerEmail, sellerPassword)
  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          ...
      }
      else {
          throw task.getException();
      }
    }
```